# Is there a 'ResponseInterceptor' (as its counterpart RequestInterceptor) component for Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit and most of its components like ErrorHandler, Callbacks and RequestInterceptor, etc. But I miss something like a 'ResponseInterceptor', something that would allow me to filter or read headers that came on the response in generic way, as a central point, instead of having to set a Callback to every service call. This is currently the only way I know how to achieve such a goal, but having to explicitly pass the callback object on very service call is not desirable.

What I want is to act upon any response that has a presence of a specific header, so it would be like a generic object (a 'ResponseInterceptor') that would analyse each response.

Is there such a thing? or any better idea on how to achieve this without having to set a Callback object on every service call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) currently doesn't provide a standard way of doing it, I managed to make it work by decorating the [retrofit.client.Client](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/Client.java) implementation that is given to the [retrofit.RestAdapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java), see it below:

**1)** define an interface for the interceptor

```
import retrofit.client.Response;

public interface ResponseInterceptor {

   void intercept(Response response);
}
```

**2)** make an implementation of it.

```
public class MyResponseInterceptor implements ResponseInterceptor {

  @Override
  public void intercept(Response response) {
    List<Header> headers = response.getHeaders();
    //... read the headers the way you like
  }
}
```

**3)** implement the decorator for the Client:

```
 public final class ResponseInterceptorClient extends OkClient {
    private final ResponseInterceptor responseInterceptor;

    public ResponseInterceptorClient(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, ResponseInterceptor responseInterceptor) {
       super(okHttpClient);
       this.responseInterceptor = responseInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        Response response = super.execute(request);
        doIntercept(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void doIntercept(Response response) {
        if (responseInterceptor != null) {
           responseInterceptor.intercept(response);
        }
    }
 }
```

**4)** then pass it on to the **RestAdapter**:

```
  RestAdapter.Builder restBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
  //...
  restBuilder.setClient(new ResponseInterceptorClient(okHttpClient, new MyResponseInterceptor()));
  //...
  restAdapter = restBuilder.build();
```

It's very simple and it could be easily make available by the library, just like the [RequestInterceptor](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RequestInterceptor.java), until it isn't, this is a way to do it. Enjoy!

**UPDATE 03/2016**: Since [Retrofit 2.0](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) there's no need for making your own ResponseInterceptor, you can make use of the [OkHttp interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) that come integrated with it.